# How to change preferred release type for a server to LTS?

Tags: server, upgrade

One of our servers in running 12.04.4 LTS.

On login, it states:

> New release '12.10' available.
>
> Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

I know it's possible to change a setting to only notify of LTS releases, and to only upgrade to LTS releases, in the desktop UI, but how do I do that for an Ubuntu Server installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set (in the `[DEFAULT]` section):

```
Prompt=lts
```

Since this MOTD is shown to you, the package `update-manager-core` is likely installed in your system. If not, install it first.

Comment: Strangely, it's already set to `lts`.

Comment: Are there any files `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d`? Those can override the preference set in this file, I think.

Comment: Nothing in there. I think perhaps there's a broken `motd` configuration. Although I don't want to risk running do-release-upgrade and have it upgrade to 12.10 instead of 14.04.

Comment: @bcmcfc you're safe in that point: `do-release-upgrade` will show you the list of changes and ask you to confirm before actually starting the upgrade. So you can test it out to see which release it's going after. There's also the `--sandbox` option.

Comment: good shout that - I checked and it picked 14.04. So it looks like the update manager config is correct. I'm going to accept your answer though since that is the right answer to the question asked. The motd issue is separate by the looks of things.

Comment: The `motd` is from a command in the `update-manager-core`. Perhaps it's a bug that was fixed in newer versions? Is there an update available for that package in your system?